# Flutter:Unable to read local json file with rootBundle

Tags: flutter, dart, null

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {

String abiStringFile="";
String path = "assets/data.json";
setUp(() async {

abiStringFile = await rootBundle.loadString(path);

});

test("Run Please", (){
print(abiStringFile);
});
}
```

Error:

```
Null check operator used on a null value.
Problem in PlatfromAssetBundle.load from services/asset_bundle.dart:223
```

pubspec.yaml file

```
flutter:

   uses-material-design: true

   assets:
     - assets/data.json
```

Answer (score 0):

try to write this in the beginning of `SetUp()`:

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```